# Vue 2 + Babel + Browserify + Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, vue.js, babel

Пробовал много разных вариантов собрать проект Vue с помощью Gulp в связке с Browserify и Babel.

```
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

const browserify = require('browserify');
const babel = require('babelify');

gulp.task('vue', function () {
    return browserify('src/main.js', { debug: true })
        .transform(babel, { presets: ["env", "stage-0", "vue"] })
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source('build.js'))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('build/js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
    })
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Версии пакетов:

- "babel-core": "^6.26.0"
- "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
- "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
- "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.0"
- "babelify": "^8.0.0"
- "browserify": "^14.5.0"
- "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
- "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда берется ошибка и как её решить?